# Ionic turn button click off in ngFor loop

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I am in Ionic 3 and have a loop in my HTML:

```
  <button ion-button *ngFor="let button of menuItems" (click)="presentPopover($event,button.children)">
    <ion-icon name="wind-flag"><div class="active">100%</div></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

I'd like to turn off the click handler if my 'button.children' array count is zero. I have had a good look around and as this angular approach is new to me, I'm having not a lot of luck. Thanks in advance.

Furthering this id like it to show me the array node button.link, grrr I cant see how!! I wrap it in {{ }} and it errors.

```
button.children.length > 0 ? presentPopover($event,button.children) : {{ button.link }}
```

Comment: You can disable the button with: `[disabled]="button.children.length === 0"`.

Comment: I removed the braces and it was working, I just didn't wrap it in my push function: button.children.length > 0 ? presentPopover($event,button.children) : pushPage(button.link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like :

```
(click)="button.children.length > 0 ? presentPopover($event,button.children) : false"
```

Comment: LoL, Thanks for the compliment , Happy Coding BTW :) .